# Existing JSP Pages need to be responsive

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, responsive-design

I need to make the existing JSP pages responsive. I handled the plain HTML files to make it responsive using the bootstrap framework. But with JSP's how it can be achieved effectively as the environment is different. Do I need any extra set up ? any example or link that can help me.

Please suggest me the best way to get it done.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: It should just be a matter of adding CSS with appropriate media queries.  That's the beauty of semantic web.

Comment: You should do it as you do in plain HTML files. In your jsp pages you have html elements or jsp tags that renders html elements, so you can apply same CSS as you do in plain html files.

Comment: need more info, are you using spring? Is this just for JSP's in general? Also see here http://gauravmishra.com/post/56228281890/introduction-to-css-for-jsp-developers

Comment: I am using struts with maven and pom environment.